# What is the proper way of returning responses in node.js express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having trouble understanding what is wrong with my code. I am creating simple node.js REST api and I'm getting error no matter what I do:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:535:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\04. MOJE\08. STUDIA\6 semestr\Wybrane technologie webowe\Projekt\silicon store api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\04. MOJE\08. STUDIA\6 semestr\Wybrane technologie webowe\Projekt\silicon store api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\04. MOJE\08. STUDIA\6 semestr\Wybrane technologie webowe\Projekt\silicon store api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\04. MOJE\08. STUDIA\6 semestr\Wybrane technologie webowe\Projekt\silicon store api\controllers\users.js:38:32)
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\04. MOJE\08. STUDIA\6 semestr\Wybrane technologie webowe\Projekt\silicon store api\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (D:\04. MOJE\08. STUDIA\6 semestr\Wybrane technologie webowe\Projekt\silicon store api\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (D:\04. MOJE\08. STUDIA\6 semestr\Wybrane technologie webowe\Projekt\silicon store api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\04. MOJE\08. STUDIA\6 semestr\Wybrane technologie webowe\Projekt\silicon store api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (D:\04. MOJE\08. STUDIA\6 semestr\Wybrane technologie webowe\Projekt\silicon store api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:133:8) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

The code that is causing the error is as follows:

```js
exports.register = function (req, res) {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  var userId;
  // check whether email is taken
  mysql.query(
    'SELECT email FROM users where email = ?',
    [req.body.email],
    (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      }
      if (rows.length > 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: 'Mail taken',
        });
      }
    }
  );
  // check whether name is taken
  mysql.query(
    'SELECT name FROM users where name = ?',
    [req.body.name],
    (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500);
      }
      if (rows.length > 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: 'Name taken',
        });
      }
    }
  );
```

where line 38 is:

```js
return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Name taken' });
```

However the response is correct and I'm getting error 400 with `error` set to `Mail taken`

From my understanding this has something to do with trying to send the response multiple times. Register function doesn't end after checking whether the name or email are taken. There is more code there, but the principle will be the same.

I don't know nor can find any information on the web what is the correct way to handle responses.

Comment: You are trying to send the response twice. The calls to `mysql.query()` aren't mutually exclusive but in sequence. And both are trying to `res.status()` etc.

Comment: m02ph3u5 What should I do then? If queries run in sequence then if the first one detects the error (or bad request) then the other one shouldn't be executed, right?

Comment: You can either run them in sequence (callback inside callback, leading to callback hell :D) or you manage your state outside the async part. You should probably use promises.

Comment: added a Promise based draft

Comment: @kazulla More then the response error, the code is buggy. Try to understand the async IO nature of nodejs. Here you are firing two MySQL queries one after another but remember it is asynchronous so it's highly possible that the sequence of queries change and you end up in confusion. So apart from fixing error of sending two responses, you need to improve on coding as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid callback hell you could use promises and manage your state outside the asynchronous parts. Maybe, whatever your `mysql` is, it already provides a promise based interface.

I'll provide you some abstract code:

If you can use async/await:

```js
// "promisified" email check
function checkEmail(email) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mysql.query(
            'SELECT email FROM users where email = ?',
            email,
            (err, rows, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject({status: 500});
                }
                if (rows.length > 0) {
                    reject({
                        status: 400,
                        message: 'Mail taken'
                    })
                }
                resolve()
            })
    })
}


// ... same for name or genralized function

exports.register = async function(req, res) {
    // ...
    const emailOk = checkEmail(req.body.email)
    const nameOk = checkName(req.body.name)

    // ...
    await Promise.all([
        emailOk,
        nameOk
    ])
    .then(() => console.log('both ok'))
    .catch(e => res.status(e.status).json(...))
}
```

Comment: I think I will try that later. Looks a lot better than nesting multiple callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the response twice, which causes the `cannot set headers` error. You would need to run the second `mysql.query` within the callback function of the first. Alternatively, you can run each of this queries using `async` `await`.

```
exports.register = function (req, res) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    var userId;
    // check whether email is taken
    mysql.query(
        'SELECT email FROM users where email = ?',
        [req.body.email],
        (err, rows, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            if (rows.length > 0) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: 'Mail taken',
                });
            }
            // check whether name is taken
            mysql.query(
                'SELECT name FROM users where name = ?',
                [req.body.name],
                (nameErr, nameRows, fields) => {
                    if (nameErr) {
                        return res.status(500);
                    }
                    if (nameRows.length > 0) {
                        return res.status(400).json({
                            message: 'Name taken',
                        });
                    }
                    // if no errors, run the rest of your code here
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This does ineed work. I tried it earlier but it wasn't working because of the rest of my code (same problem).

Comment: Would be better if you used promises, as you might end up having too many callbacks.